# Python Selenium - Automatic click login to webpage not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am losing my mind here and cannot find what error could or if something is missing.

I am trying to automate the login process using Python and Selenium. When I step into each line of my code, it works without any issue. But if I just press run and the code is completed without any issue but it doesn't log in.

It logs in when I keep the chrome screen on the side like the image below but not when I just don't do anything after running the code.
[image: Login works on side]

This is my code to click the button

```
try:
    cookies_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept Cookies']")
    cookies_Button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Cookies Button click failed")

try:
    Login_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Login'][@type='button']")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,'Login')))
    print("Button is ready")
    #time.sleep(10)
    actions = ActionChains(driver) 
    actions.move_to_element(Login_Button).click().perform()
    time.sleep(30)
except:
    print("Login Button click failed")
```

Any help will be appreciated on how I can log in automatically.

Comment: Is there any code after this ?

Comment: Always post entire code with such questions. I have seen it saves a lot of time. If we can reproduce the problem by copying the code. Otherwise you just keep going back and forth because the issue was somewhere else in the script.

Comment: @AbhishekRai  I have added the complete code now in the description. This should give the response that please enter correct email and password. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't see any issues with that code. Maybe the site doesn't work without accepting cookies.
try accepting and check if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies were creating an issue. Adding the cokkies click helped resolving the issue

```
try:
    cookies_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Accept Cookies']")
    cookies_Button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Cookies Button click failed")
```